# Laravel Queries and Cache

Tags: select, laravel, browser-cache

I am trying to store a table in cache and display it in a view.  But when I do this it also saves the column ID as well.  I do not want to display this ID.  I have a lot of columns in a table.  Is there a simple way to `get all but one column from a table`? I have seen ways to choose how to select multiple columns, but this unnecessary for what I need.  Especially with 20+ columns.  This is my code in the controller.

```
 $table1 = DB::table('table1')->get();
 return Cache::put('table1 ', $table1 , 60);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an array of field names to get().

```
$table1 = DB::table('table1')->get(array('field1','field1'));
```

Also, have you looked into using ->remember(60) instead of Cache?